# Binding more table in one grid Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I have a table manage `Sub-Categories` using Kendo UI. Now, I want add a field to create a new photo for each product with `ProductName`, `ProductID`, but a `PhotoId` and `ProductName` are in another table. How can I binding two or more tables in one Grid?

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var subcateViewModel = GetSubProduct();
            return View(subcateViewModel);
        }
        //Get SubCategory
        public ActionResult GetSub([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetSubProduct().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
private IEnumerable<SubCateViewModel> GetSubProduct()
        {
            var context = new AdvenDBEntities();
            var subcate = context.ProductSubcategories.Select(sub => new SubCateViewModel
                {
                    ProductSubcategoryID = sub.ProductSubcategoryID,
                    ProductCategoryID = sub.ProductCategoryID,
                    NameofBike = sub.NameofBike,
                    isSelected = sub.isSelected,
                });
            return subcate;
        }
```

Is there any example related with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo Grid doesn't bind to tables it Binds to Objects, in this case your ViewModel. In your LinQ query you will build a statement that joins 2 or more tables. Something like this.

```
public List<OrderGridViewModel> GetOrders()
    {
        using (var context = new TropicalServerEntities())
        {
            return (from cust in context.tblCustomer
                    join ord in context.tblOrder on cust.CustNumber equals ord.OrderCustomerNumber
                    select new OrderGridViewModel
                    {
                        TrackingNo = ord.OrderTrackingNumber,
                        RouteNo = (int)ord.OrderRouteNumber,
                        OrderId = ord.OrderID,
                        OrderDate = (DateTime)ord.OrderDate,
                        CustomerName = cust.CustName,
                        CustomerId = cust.CustID,
                        Address = cust.CustOfficeAddress1
                    }).Take(10).ToList();
        }
    }
```